# Создание общей папки (Windows) для пользователей в локальной сети. Желателен доступ к ней извне. Решения?

Tags: windows, сеть, nas

Имеется ноутбук, работающий 24\7. Он подключен к сети, имеющей доступ к Интернету. ОС - Windows 10. И на нем есть свободное место, которое хочется использовать. Копировать с телефона файлы, с ноута, чтобы был, так сказать, сетевой буфер.

Можно средствами Windows создать папку и настроить общий доступ, но не получится добраться к ней извне (или я не прав?). И не получится сконфигурировать максимальный размер этот папки.

Слышал про NAS (гугл рассказал, но я руками не трогал, может чего не понял), а также то, что такие решения обычно на *nix системах.

Подскажите софт для подобного применения (или общая папка - лучшее?). 
Как пример, было бы удобно, если эту папку было бы видно как ещё один диск в "Этом компьютере".

Спасибо, извиняюсь, если вопрос очевидный.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/875055/315697 - ты не первый. И точно не последний.